# Is it possible that we had been born as humans before this very life?

Tags: philosophy, belief, dharma-shastras

Is it that Human births for each soul take place after long periods of time?

Comment: I have read somewhere that brahmins must have been humans in their previous life - hence "twice-born"

Comment: @SK - that has nothing to do with meaning 'twice born'. All of us have had innumerable lives in the past. Twice Born or Dwija means the birth of Jnana during Upanayana around age 8 in the same birth.

Comment: @mar "birth of Jnana during Upanayana": could you explain what this means?

Comment: Sacred thread ceremony https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upanayana

Comment: @mar oh ok. thank you

Comment: reincarnation is one of the assertions of all Hindus. Whether it was as a human before or not is dependent upon an individual jiva's karma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible that we had been born as humans before ?

Yes.

[Bhagavad Gita 4.5](https://asitis.com/4/5.html)

> bahuni me vyatitani janmani tava carjuna
> tany aham veda sarvani na tvam vettha parantapa
>
> Many, many births both you and I have passed.
> I can remember all of them, but you cannot, O subduer of the enemy!

e.g. Arjuna was previously Indra. Bhishma was previously Vasu. Innumerable such examples.

> Is it that Human births for each soul take place after long periods of time ?

Yes.

[Vivekachudamani](https://www.advaita-vedanta.org/series/viveka/verse_2.htm)

> jantUnAm narajanma durlabham atah pumstvam tato vipratA tasmad
> vaidikadharmamArgaparatA vidvatvam asmAt param |
> AtmAnAtmavivecanam svanubhavo brahmAtmanA samstitih muktirno satakotijanmasu krtaih:
> punyairvinA labhyate ||
>
> Of all births, that as a human being is rare to obtain. rarer still is
> to be born as a male; rarer than that is to be born a BrAhmana. More
> difficult than that is to be inclined towards the path of dharma
> declared by the Vedas. Successively more difficult than this are
> scholarships (in the revealed texts).
> Discrimination between the Atman
> and anAtman, perfect experience following profound meditation, the
> state of being established in Brahman and lastly, mukti or liberation.
> These cannot be obtained without merit acquired in hundreds of crores
> of lives.

Comment: When Krishna said "Many, many births I have passed", was he referring to Vishnu's previous avataras?

Comment: @LearningHindu - yes, Krishna is same as Vishnu. an avatar is just like dressing up in different clothes and going to a different place. It's the same person.

Comment: Re: *Arjuna was previously Indra. Bhishma was previously Vasu.* I thought Arjuna was the son of Indra.

Comment: @SeverusSnape - he is. but in his previous janma, he himself was an Indra, as were the other 4 pandavas.